# New Powershell User - Import Export From CSV but Only if modified today

Tags: powershell, csv

I know this is incorrect but I want to use a csv for source and destination of files to copy (which works fine) but I also want to add logic to only copy if it was modifed today. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
$MyDate = (Get-Date).date
Import-Csv Y:\copytest.csv | foreach {Copy-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination 
    | Where {$_.lastwritetime -gt $MyDate } }
```

Im guessing I need to activate the actual file from the $_.Source to then be able to get .lastwritetime any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Managed to solve it now with this... $MyDate = (Get-Date).date
Write-Host $MyDate
Import-Csv Y:\copytest.csv | foreach { 
                                        if ($(Get-Item -Path $_.Source).lastwritetime -gt $MyDate)
                                        {
                                            Copy-Item -Path $_.Source -Destination $_.Destination
                                        } 
                                     }

Comment: post this as an answer so that others might benefit from it! Posting code in comments is really really bad - it cannot be properly formatted, and it's really hard to read - don't do it, please!